# Any rich text editor that edits html "As It Is"?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I'm having a hard time finding a good WYSIWYG editor, tried CKeditor & TinyMCE and found out that they strip out a lot of tags and headers and they ruin the page.

Any recommendations of professional editors? i want it to leave the page as it is but only change the areas that people "touched".

Thanks

Comment: I've used CKEditor for what you're mentioning and it's worked fine for me... Can't really guess what your problem is!

Comment: It's stripping out any meta tags and adding weired breaks in the page, you have to try it on a bit more complex pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE and other editors as-default usually do some level of clean up.

For example with TinyMCE there are configuration options such as [cleanup](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/cleanup) and [clean up on startup](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/cleanup_on_startup) which can be used to control the cleanup actions.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    cleanup : false
});
```

Documentation as taken from TinyMCE wiki:

This option enables or disables the built-in clean up functionality. TinyMCE is equipped with powerful clean up functionality that enables you to specify what elements and attributes are allowed and how HTML contents should be generated.

This option is **set to `true` by default**, but if you want to disable it you may set it to `false`.

**Notice: It's not recommended to disable this feature.**
It might be worth mentioning that the browser usually messes with the HTML. The clean up not only fixes several problems with the browsers' parsed HTML document, like paths etc., it also makes sure it is a correct XHTML document, with all tags closed, the " at the right places, and things like that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, any idea of the same function but for CKeditor?

Comment: @David all of CKEditors options can be found here: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html although I am not sure if it provides the the same configuration option.

Comment: CKeditor has got a lot of configurations that you can go through, though when i used it last, their docs were sub par at best and there wasnt much support. Im sure there is some way to do what you want, because if i remember correctly, some of the code ive used before has done that

Comment: Just found out a solution, adding: **config.fullPage = true;** in **config.js** resolves the issue !

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything like this before but was thinking of trying to create something like this